# Replace part of URL with value from button

Tags: javascript, html, button

But first: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkQ3Y/)

What I'm trying to achieve is that when you press the button, it replaces the # in this link

```
 http://www.twitch.tv/#/chat?popout=
```

with what you typed in the text box and redirects you there.

I tried doing something with this:

```
var link = 'http://www.twitch.tv/#/chat?popout=';

var fullreplace = link.replace( ' ', ' ');
```

but I can't really figure quite out what to do.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you please show the button to be clicked and *precisely* what the URL should be/become.

Comment: You can see the button in the fiddle I posted, and I want the # in the URL to change to what gets typed in the text box. e.g. http://www.twitch.tv/#/chat?popout= changes to http://www.twitch.tv/TEST/chat?popout= if you type TEST and it should redirect you there.

Comment: Indeed, but we shouldn't have to traipse around the internet in order to help you. Your question should be self contained, and reduced to the minimum necessary code to reproduce your problem. A live demo, at JS Fiddle or elsewhere, is a bonus but your code should be present in your question. For further information (as to *why*): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: I will keep that in mind, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Skipping the JavaScript:

```
<form>
Channel Name: <input type="text" id="channel" name="Channel"><br>
<input type="button" value="Go to Channel" onClick="window.location.href='http://www.twitch.tv/' + document.getElementById('channel').value + '/chat?popout='">
</form>
```

Comment: How is using it inline skipping Javascript?

Comment: I knew there'd be someone to Nit-pick on that phrase. What I meant was that I'm ignoring the `var link...` part of his code in favor of inlining the JS.

Comment: It's generally for the best to separate your layout from your functional logic, not inline it.

Comment: Agreed. I chose the easiest way because we were dealing with very basic code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to write it out for you, but give your input an id. Write a function that gets triggered onClick on your button. Use var link and document.getElementById to combine those two in the function and then forward the user to that new url.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to use `replace`, it's often more readable to just do the following:

[**Sample Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/22EHc/).

JS:

```
document.getElementById("clicker").onclick = function() {
    var link = "http://www.twitch.tv/#/chat?popout=";
    link = link.split('#').join(document.getElementById('channel_name').value);
    console.log(link);
}
```

HTML:

```
<form>
Channel Name: <input type="text" name="Channel" id="channel_name"><br>
<input type="button" value="Go to Channel" id="clicker" />
</form>
```

Comment: umm, ur sample fiddle aint fiddling.

Comment: @Charles Yes it is, as long as you know what a Javascript console is.

Comment: Okay, just tried it again with console on firefox and it worked. No need to be a smarty pants, lol.

Comment: @Charles It's obvious from reading the code that the address is written to the console and won't be acted upon.